# Shell variable inside sshagent block of a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have this sshagent code block:

```
            sshagent(['ssh_key.hashed']) {
              sh """
              ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user example.com <<EOF
              today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
              drush -r /var/www/html/example.com sql-dump --gzip > /var/www/html/example.com/backups/example_prodDB-jenkins-${today}.sql.gz
              EOF
              """.stripIndent()
            }
```

Where as you can see, the real intention is to get the db dump of a drupal database. 
Now, it will work if used on a regular shell script.

I need to write it that way as I will reuse the `$today` shell variable in another line of code.

Within the jenkinsfile, it seems like it is interpreted as a groovy variable based on the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: today for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:11)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor305.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any hints is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the shell variable.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard. However, it only fixes the syntax error and still outside what I was looking for. After a lot of searches and trial and error, I used an environment variable and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching online and trial and error found this helpful reference https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables

I don't know if it's the right way to do it but it works.

So in summary, I had to add an environment variable and add use it within my "sshagent"

Posting sample Jenkinsfile that works.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Dump Prod DB') {
           environment {
               today = sh(script: 'date +%Y-%m-%d', , returnStdout: true).trim()
           }
         steps {
            sshagent(['promet_key.hashed']) {
              sh """
              ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user example.com <<EOF
              drush -r /var/www/html/example.com sql-dump --gzip > /var/www/html/example.com/backups/example_prodDB-jenkins-${today}.sql.gz
              EOF
              """.stripIndent()
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```